# tidymodels does not respect fixed set_engine parameters

Tags: r, tidymodels

(**Updated** at the end based on Julia's reply. **TL;DR**: This seems to be an issue with the underlying **kknn** package, instead of with **tidymodels**)

I'm doing some k-nearest neighbours regression models with tidymodels. This is through the `nearest_neighbor()` function.  I want to see what the difference is between the results with and without normalization of the features.

Now `set_engine("kknn")` uses the `kknn::train.kknn()` function under the hood, which has a normalization argument `scale = TRUE`. I want to compare models with `scale = FALSE` to `scale = TRUE` (actually, I want to do that in a recipe, but that is not possible, as I'll explain below).

But it does not seem as if I am able to reliably set `scale = FALSE` through tidymodels. Below is a reprex showing what I see.

The **questions** so long: Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? If it is a bug, is it known and can I read about it somewhere? I'd be very grateful if someone can shed light on this.

### Set up for the reprex

Here I'll use `mtcars`:

```
library(tidymodels)
data("mtcars")
```

A train-test split is:

```
set.seed(1)
mtcars_split <- initial_split(mtcars, prop = 0.7)
```

Here is a common recipe I'll use:

```
mtcars_recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ disp + wt, data = mtcars)
```

Here is model 1 (called `knn_FALSE`) where `scale = FALSE`:

```
knn_FALSE <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = 5) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("kknn", scale = FALSE)
```

Here is model 2 (called `knn_TRUE`) where `scale = TRUE`:

```
knn_TRUE <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = 5) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("kknn", scale = TRUE)
```

I bundle these two models into two workflows:

```
## Workflow with scale = FALSE
wf_FALSE <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_FALSE) %>% 
  add_recipe(mtcars_recipe)

## Worflow with scale = TRUE
wf_TRUE <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_TRUE) %>% 
  add_recipe(mtcars_recipe)
```

### Using `fit()`, it is possible to have `scale = FALSE`

It does seem to be possible to have one version with `scale = TRUE` and one with `scale = FALSE` when using `fit()` on a workflow.

For example, for `scale = TRUE` I get:

```
wf_TRUE %>% fit(mtcars)
== Workflow [trained] ===============================================================================================
Preprocessor: Recipe
Model: nearest_neighbor()

-- Preprocessor -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 Recipe Steps

-- Model ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Call:
kknn::train.kknn(formula = ..y ~ ., data = data, ks = ~5, scale = ~TRUE)

Type of response variable: continuous
minimal mean absolute error: 2.09425
Minimal mean squared error: 7.219114
Best kernel: optimal
Best k: 5
```

Whereas for `scale = FALSE` I have:

```
wf_FALSE %>% fit(mtcars)
== Workflow [trained] ===============================================================================================
Preprocessor: Recipe
Model: nearest_neighbor()

-- Preprocessor -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 Recipe Steps

-- Model ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Call:
kknn::train.kknn(formula = ..y ~ ., data = data, ks = ~5, scale = ~FALSE)

Type of response variable: continuous
minimal mean absolute error: 2.1665
Minimal mean squared error: 6.538769
Best kernel: optimal
Best k: 5
```

The results are clearly different, which comes from the difference in the `scale` parameter.

But the plot thickens.

### No difference with `last_fit()`

When using `last_fit()` however, the results for `scale = TRUE` and `scale = FALSE` are identical though.

For `scale = TRUE`:

```
wf_TRUE %>% last_fit(mtcars_split) %>% collect_metrics()
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  .metric .estimator .estimate
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 rmse    standard       3.16 
2 rsq     standard       0.663
```

Whereas for `scale = FALSE`:

```
wf_FALSE %>% last_fit(mtcars_split) %>% collect_metrics()
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  .metric .estimator .estimate
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 rmse    standard       3.16 
2 rsq     standard       0.663
```

These are clearly --- and unexpectedly --- the same.

### There is also no difference when tuning using `tune_grid()`

If I do tuning with `tune_grid()` and a `validation_split()`, there is also no difference between the results for `scale = TRUE` and `scale = FALSE`.

Here is the code for that:

```
## Tune grid
knn_grid <- tibble(neighbors = c(5, 15))

## Tune Model 1: kNN regresson with no scaling in train.kknn
knn_FALSE_tune <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("kknn", scale = FALSE)

## Model 2: kNN regresson with  scaling in train.kknn
knn_TRUE_tune <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("kknn", scale = TRUE)

## Workflow with scale = FALSE
wf_FALSE_tune <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_FALSE_tune) %>% 
  add_recipe(mtcars_recipe)

## Worflow with scale = TRUE
wf_TRUE_tune <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_TRUE_tune) %>% 
  add_recipe(mtcars_recipe)

## Validation split
mtcars_val <- validation_split(mtcars)

## Tune results: Without scaling
wf_FALSE_tune %>% 
  tune_grid(resamples = mtcars_val, 
            grid = knn_grid) %>% 
  collect_metrics()

## Tune results: With scaling
wf_TRUE_tune %>% 
  tune_grid(resamples = mtcars_val, 
            grid = knn_grid) %>% 
  collect_metrics()
```

The result when `scale = FALSE`:

```
> wf_FALSE_tune %>% 
+   tune_grid(resamples = mtcars_val, 
+             grid = knn_grid) %>% 
+   collect_metrics()
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  neighbors .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err .config
      <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>  
1         5 rmse    standard   1.64      1      NA Model1 
2         5 rsq     standard   0.920     1      NA Model1 
3        15 rmse    standard   2.55      1      NA Model2 
4        15 rsq     standard   0.956     1      NA Model2
```

The results when `scale = TRUE`:

```
> wf_TRUE_tune %>% 
+   tune_grid(resamples = mtcars_val, 
+             grid = knn_grid) %>% 
+   collect_metrics()
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  neighbors .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err .config
      <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>  
1         5 rmse    standard   1.64      1      NA Model1 
2         5 rsq     standard   0.920     1      NA Model1 
3        15 rmse    standard   2.55      1      NA Model2 
4        15 rsq     standard   0.956     1      NA Model2
```

### Question

Am I misunderstanding (or missing my own bug), or are the `last_fit()` and `tune_grid()` functions not respecting my choice for `scale`?

I'm new to tidymodels, so I might have missed something. Answers much appreciated.

I was hoping to use `step_normalize()` in a recipe to do the normalization myself, but since I cannot reliably set `scale = FALSE` in the underlying engine, I have not been able to experiment with that.

### Update after Julia's reply

As Julia shows, predictions from `train.kknn()` provide the same predictions for `scale = FALSE` and `scale = TRUE`. So this isn't an **tidymodels** issue. Rather the `kknn:::predict.train.kknn()` function does not respect all parameters passed to `train.kknn()` when predicting.

Consider the following output which uses `kknn()` instead of `train.kknn()`:

```r
kknn::kknn(formula = mpg ~ disp + wt, train = training(mtcars_split), 
           test = testing(mtcars_split), k = 5, scale = FALSE) %>% 
  predict(newdata = testing(mtcars_split))
## [1] 21.276 21.276 16.860 16.276 21.276 16.404 29.680 15.700 16.020
kknn::kknn(formula = mpg ~ disp + wt, train = training(mtcars_split), 
           test = testing(mtcars_split), k = 5, scale = TRUE) %>% 
  predict(newdata = testing(mtcars_split))
## [1] 21.032 21.784 16.668 16.052 21.264 16.404 26.340 16.076 15.620
```

These are different, as it should be. The problem is that `kknn:::predict.train.kknn()` calls `kknn()`, but without passing along `scale` (and some other optional arguments):

```r
function (object, newdata, ...) 
{
    if (missing(newdata)) 
        return(predict(object, ...))
    res <- kknn(formula(terms(object)), object$data, newdata, 
        k = object$best.parameters$k, kernel = object$best.parameters$kernel, 
        distance = object$distance)
    return(predict(res, ...))
}
<bytecode: 0x55e2304fba10>
<environment: namespace:kknn>
```

Comment: I've reported this to the kknn maintainer on Github here: https://github.com/KlausVigo/kknn/issues/22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have a bug or problem but are just misunderstanding what `last_fit()` and friends are predicting on to estimate performance.

```r
library(tidymodels)
set.seed(1)
mtcars_split <- initial_split(mtcars, prop = 0.7)

knn_FALSE <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = 5) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("kknn", scale = FALSE)

knn_FALSE %>% translate()
#> K-Nearest Neighbor Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   neighbors = 5
#> 
#> Engine-Specific Arguments:
#>   scale = FALSE
#> 
#> Computational engine: kknn 
#> 
#> Model fit template:
#> kknn::train.kknn(formula = missing_arg(), data = missing_arg(), 
#>     ks = min_rows(5, data, 5), scale = FALSE)

knn_TRUE <- nearest_neighbor(neighbors = 5) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("kknn", scale = TRUE)

knn_TRUE %>% translate()
#> K-Nearest Neighbor Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   neighbors = 5
#> 
#> Engine-Specific Arguments:
#>   scale = TRUE
#> 
#> Computational engine: kknn 
#> 
#> Model fit template:
#> kknn::train.kknn(formula = missing_arg(), data = missing_arg(), 
#>     ks = min_rows(5, data, 5), scale = TRUE)
```

Notice that both parsnip models are correctly passing the `scale` parameter to the underlying engine.

We can now add these two parsnip models to a `workflow()`, with a formula preprocessor (a recipe would be fine too).

```r
wf_FALSE <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_FALSE) %>% 
  add_formula(mpg ~ disp + wt)

## Worflow with scale = TRUE
wf_TRUE <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_TRUE) %>% 
  add_formula(mpg ~ disp + wt)
```

The function `last_fit()` **fits** on the training data and **predicts** on the testing data. We can do that manually with our workflows. Importantly, notice that for these examples in the testing set, the predictions are *the same*, so the metrics you would get are the same.

```r
wf_TRUE %>% fit(training(mtcars_split)) %>% predict(testing(mtcars_split))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   .pred
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  21.0
#> 2  21.8
#> 3  16.7
#> 4  16.1
#> 5  21.3
#> 6  16.4
#> 7  26.3
#> 8  16.1
#> 9  15.6
wf_FALSE %>% fit(training(mtcars_split)) %>% predict(testing(mtcars_split))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   .pred
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  21.0
#> 2  21.8
#> 3  16.7
#> 4  16.1
#> 5  21.3
#> 6  16.4
#> 7  26.3
#> 8  16.1
#> 9  15.6
```

The same thing is true for fitting the models directly:

```r
knn_TRUE %>% 
  fit(mpg ~ disp + wt, data = training(mtcars_split)) %>% 
  predict(testing(mtcars_split))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   .pred
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  21.0
#> 2  21.8
#> 3  16.7
#> 4  16.1
#> 5  21.3
#> 6  16.4
#> 7  26.3
#> 8  16.1
#> 9  15.6
knn_FALSE %>% 
  fit(mpg ~ disp + wt, data = training(mtcars_split)) %>% 
  predict(testing(mtcars_split))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   .pred
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  21.0
#> 2  21.8
#> 3  16.7
#> 4  16.1
#> 5  21.3
#> 6  16.4
#> 7  26.3
#> 8  16.1
#> 9  15.6
```

And in fact is true if we fit the underlying kknn model directly:

```r
kknn::train.kknn(formula = mpg ~ disp + wt, data = training(mtcars_split), 
                 ks = 5, scale = FALSE) %>% 
  predict(testing(mtcars_split))
#> [1] 21.032 21.784 16.668 16.052 21.264 16.404 26.340 16.076 15.620
kknn::train.kknn(formula = mpg ~ disp + wt, data = training(mtcars_split), 
                 ks = 5, scale = TRUE) %>% 
  predict(testing(mtcars_split))
#> [1] 21.032 21.784 16.668 16.052 21.264 16.404 26.340 16.076 15.620
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

The `scale` parameter is correctly being passed to the underlying engine; it just doesn't change the prediction for these test cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this, Julia, and for your great work on these packages. I should have checked the kknn package first. It looks like there is an issue with predict.train.kknn() where the non-usual arguments like scale isn't respected. So the predictions are the same, but it should not be. It would have worked fine using kknn() instead of train.kknn() though. I'll update the question above to report this.